# Automatically update javascript elements when internal Anchor/Hash is clicked

Tags: javascript, anchor

I would like to display the updated Anchor/Hash in `id="demo"` when a link is clicked. The layout of the document is as follows.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=location.hash;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Javascript</h1>
<p id="demo">This is a paragraph.</p>

<a href="#example" onclick="myfunction()">here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Only problem is when the link is clicked the javascript does not get the updated Anchor/Hash until the link is pressed for a second time.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the location hasn't changed at this time. Here is a way you can use:

```
function myfunction() {
    // Sets the event handler once you click, so it will execute when
    // the hash will change.
    window.onhashchange = function() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=location.hash;
    };
}
```

A modern way would be:

```
var hashchange;
function myfunction() {
    if ( !hashchange ) {
        hashchange = addEventListener( 'change', function() {
            document.getElementById("demo").textContent = location.hash;

            // If you want to remove the event listener right after,
            // you can do this:
            removeEventListener( hashchange );
        }, false );
    }
}
```

Comment: IE8 supports this, IE7 doesn't ([source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=hashchange)). Do you really support IE7? You use jQuery then.

Comment: In this case event will be attached every time you execute a function. So when You click 7 times you will have 7 events. There should be no function at all.

Comment: @jcubic you won't have 7 events, because the "old school" events can only have one event handler. But yes, you're setting the same everytime. You'd have 7 event handlers if you were to use `addEventListener`.

Comment: @jcubic however, you may want to set the event listener only once you click, thus why it's in this function.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Yes, that's right, if not it will be dynamic, every time hash change it will change the content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this JQuery plugin for detecting the hash change:

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/

It's open-source, so check out the [code](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/), which is surprisingly complex-- 300+ lines (annotated, but still).

Comment: Surprisingly long? It has over 200 lines of comments.

Answer (score 0):

It is because "location" refers to an anchor WITHIN the page.

The first click, you have no location within the page, but the anchor takes you to #example, but all this happens after the onclick has done its business. The second click we have a location of #example.

See the [W3 Schools documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp).

The onclick event is fired before the anchor has had chance to do its job. This is crucial to being able to cancel the propagation of the event and prevent redirection etc. but sadly knobbles your code.

Comment: But I was hoping that the `onclick="myfunction()"` would run the javascript however the javascript is run before the page is updated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myfunction() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=location.hash;
  }, 1);
}
```

because when you click in the link the hash is still your prevous one so you need a delay.